# How can automatic find compression method?

Tags: format, compression

I have a compressed file starting with the hex:

> 8F AF AC 84

Can any one tell me what's the type of compression or at least a program that decompress my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/8fadbdb3/#1e6b) that would be a .pmd file.

An alternative extension would be .ppmd. It is a file compressed using [Prediction by Partial Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching).

Hope that helps, but I'm voting to close as this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, i check my file with 7z and it extracted successfully, with special thanks

Comment: @javad I've given you a +1 for properly maintaining your question, but StackOveflow is a *programming* site. In the future you can look at the list of technology sites [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology). Questions like this are probably better suited for: http://superuser.com/ or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/